# Creating Nested JSON in ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm trying to create a JSON dataset similar to the following:

```
'[{"COLUMNS":[{ "title": "NAME"}, { "title": "COUNTY"}],"DATA":[["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]}]'
```

In the past, I've only ever had to use an array of structures and then use #serializeJSON(array)# to generate simple JSON such as:

```
<cfset dataArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfoutput query="getData">
    <cfset dataStruct = StructNew() >
    <cfset dataStruct["date"] = getData.tempDate>
    <cfset dataStruct["yaxis1"] = getData.Value>
    <cfset dataStruct["label1"] = getData.Label>
</cfoutput>
<cfset ArrayAppend(dataArray,dataStruct) />
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(dataArray)#</cfoutput>
```

To generate:

```
[{"date":"2015-01-15 00:05:00","label1":"Depth","yaxis1":"0.940"},{"date":"2015-01-15 00:10:00","label1":"Depth","yaxis1":"0.940"}]
```

How does one create a nested JSON dataset with both COLUMNS and DATA recordsets?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think if you create a query object and then serialize it as JSON, it will look like that.

Comment: @DavidFaber: yup. Make that an answer so we can upvote you & get you some precious precious StackOverflow *points*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the format ColdFusion uses when serializing query objects into JSON. If you want to create a JSON object that looks like the following:

```
[{"COLUMNS":[{ "title": "NAME"}, { "title": "COUNTY"}],"DATA":[["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]}]
```

what you want to do is this:

```
<cfset myquery = queryNew("name,county", "CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_VARCHAR") /> <!--- The second parameter is optional but a good habit to get into --->
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "name", "John Doe") />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "county", "Fresno") />
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "name", "Billy") />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "county", "Fresno") />
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "name", "Tom") />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "county", "Kern") />
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "name", "King Smith") />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "county", "Kings") />

<cfset myqueryJSON = serializeJSON(myquery) />

<cfoutput>#myqueryJSON#</cfoutput>
```

The format is particularly useful when consuming ColdFusion web services from ColdFusion - you can deserialize the JSON object and use it as a query right away. It goes without saying that you can do this with `<cfquery>` as well:

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="mydatasource">
    SELECT name, county
      FROM mytable
</cfquery>

<cfset myqueryJSON = serializeJSON(myquery) />
```

There are plenty of tools that can help you transform a struct or array of structs into a query if need be.

**UPDATE per OP's comments**

We have the following:

```
"COLUMNS":["NAME","COUNTY"]
```

That needs to be in the following format:

```
"COLUMNS":[{ "title": "NAME"}, { "title": "COUNTY"}]
```

This solution is a bit kludgy, if you ask me, and I'm sure there's a more elegant one, but it does seem to work from my tests:

```
<cfset column_match = REMatchNoCase('"columns":\[[^\]]+\]', myqueryJSON)[1] />
<cfset newcolumns = REReplace(column_match , '("[^"]+"(?=[,\]]))', '{"title":\1}', "All") />
<cfset myqueryJSON = replace(myqueryJSON, column_match, newcolumns) />
```

You can find an explanation of the regex I used in the `REReplace()` at [this Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL8gJ6/1). It seems to work for any number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I added  a couple of additional queryAddRows and then brackets around the JSON output to get it into valid format.  `<cfset myquery = queryNew("name,county", "CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_VARCHAR") /> <!--- The second parameter is optional but a good habit to get into --->
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "name", "John Doe") />
<cfset querySetCell(myquery, "county", "Fresno") />
<cfset queryAddRow(myquery) />
<cfset myqueryJSON = serializeJSON(myquery) />
<cfoutput>[#myqueryJSON#]</cfoutput> `

Comment: I spoke too soon -- this actually didn't create valid JSON when I added to my JavaScript.  This is the output: `[{"COLUMNS":["NAME","COUNTY"],"DATA":[["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]}]` when it needs to be like this: `[{"COLUMNS":[{ "title": "NAME"}, { "title": "COUNTY"}],"DATA":[["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]}`

Comment: The columns still aren't in name value pairs.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why do you need the columns in name/value pairs?

Comment: I'm using the jQuery plugin called, 'DataTables', and the JSON recordset needs to be in this particular format in order for it to dynamically create columns.  Here's the JS: `var dataObject = eval('[{"COLUMNS":[{ "title": "NAME"}, { "title": "COUNTY"}],"DATA":[["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]}]');$('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataObject [0].DATA,
        "columns": dataObject [0].COLUMNS
    });`